# IE and resizing div on window.resize

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, zurb-foundation, window-resize

Im using foundation css (http://foundation.zurb.com/index.html) and I have my layout all complete. it's full page responsive.

My biggest issue is with responsive DIV background images, and heights. Basically, I have a full width row, inside of that, I have a nested row split in 2 (50/50). Example:

```
<div class="row"><!-- full row -->
  <div class="large-6 columns bgimg resizeit">row one with BG image</div><!-- left box -->
  <div class="large-6 columns setboxtall"> <!-- right box -->

    <!-- MSG-MSG -->
    <div class="valignmiddle center-it">
      <p>EVENTS | EL PASO</p>
      <h2>Event one</h2>
      <h3>MAY 26 - 27, 2014</h3>
      <hr class="block-divider" />
      <h4> Neque porro quisquam </h4>
    </div>
    <!-- MSG-MSG --> 

  </div>
</div>
```

Now, in order to see the background image in the left box, I needed a way to resize it to the height of the box on the right.

So I have a jquery script to do just that:

```
var resizeDiv = function () {
var maxHeight = 0;

  $(".setboxtall").each(function(){
     if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) { maxHeight = $(this).height(); }
  });

  $(".resizeit").height(maxHeight);

};

$(document).ready(resizeDiv);
$(window).resize(resizeDiv);
```

This basically goes through the code, looks for a class called setboxtall, and then applies THAT height, to the div called resizeit.

I am using backstretch (http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/) to apply the BG image. Works great.

```
<script>$(".bgimg").backstretch("img/background/indian.jpg");</script>
```

This works great in Firefox, Chrome and Safari. However, IE will NOT fill the div with the background image until the browser is resized. Once I resize IE even the tiniest bit, it works.

How can I get the background image to appear in that div, when the page is loaded, in IE (im using IE10 btw).

I've tried all kinds of things, my issue is isolated to the JS and resize events of div and browser.

If there is a better way to handle this, please explain.

I should alos mention, that there is anywhere from 2-6 instances of this on a page. so I need to be able to target specific div classes. (height is dynamic, based on the amount of text in the right box)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can't help directly as I don't have much experience with using Jquery for responsive purposes, but Foundation does have a plugin built in which will keep the divs at an equal height.

I think this was added in a recent update to Foundation so you may need to update to use it http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/equalizer.html